# Error: Error creating openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2

Tags: terraform, openstack

When I try to create a `openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2` in terraform I'm getting the following error,

> Error: Error creating openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2: Bad request with: [POST https://nova-cc.hou-01.cloud.prod.acme.net:8774/v2.1/servers/REDACTED_UUID/action], error message: {"badRequest": {"code": 400, "message": "Unable to associate floating IP 10.2.66.173 to fixed IP 10.2.65.167 for instance REDACTED_UUID. Error: External network REDACTED_UUID is not reachable from subnet REDACTED_UUID.  Therefore, cannot associate Port REDACTED_UUID with a Floating IP.\nNeutron server returns request_ids: ['req-a35d140e-3061-4d2d-a88b-7dfb634340c7']"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this ended up being because my system administrator disabled Floating IPs. I was getting the same error in OpenStack Horizons (the web interface).

[image]